# Almost sure convergence of a sum of truncated dependent variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, be a sequence of identically distributed real random variables such that $X_i \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_i) < \infty$.

Denoting the indicator function by $\mathbb{I}$, is it true for the truncated random variables that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}( \{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3}) = 0\}) = 1, 
\end{equation}
without further assumptions?

I have tried the following:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}( \{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3}) = 0\}) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}( \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3}) > \frac{1}{k}\})  & \\
&\geq 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}( \{ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3}) > \frac{1}{k}\}) & \mbox{ (Union bound)} \\
&\geq 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} k \mathbb{E}( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3})) & \mbox{ (Markov's inequality)} \\
\end{align}

Dominated convergence holds: $\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3})) \leq \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i$, which has a finite mean $E(X_i)$ by linearity, so the expectation and the limit can be exchanged:

\begin{align}
( \ldots ) &= 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} k \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E} ( \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n^3} X_i \mathbb{I}(X_i>n^{1/3})) \\
&= 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} k \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E} ( X_1 \mathbb{I}(X_1>n^{1/3})).
\end{align}
Again, by dominated convergence
\begin{align}
( \ldots ) &= 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} k \mathbb{E} ( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  X_1 \mathbb{I}(X_1>n^{1/3})) \\
 &= 1 - \sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}} k \mathbb{E} ( 0) \\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Any comments are welcome.

Comment: the dominated convergence seems suspicious. The dominating term should be independent of n. Even for the generalised dominated convergence theorem(see exercise 7.2 in http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/rags100514.pdf), one requires more conditions.  Also you may replace the" lim" in the set by "limsup"

Comment: You're right, Chival. I think I have to assume at least some finite moments to get this to work.